# How to filter on properties of children object and return the parent with children that passes the filter in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I want to filter on the property of children object and return parents with children that passes the filter.

I tried with combination of Array.filter, Array.some, and Object.values, but I can't think of a way to get the key back once Ive used Object.values

```
var data = {
    parent1: {
        child1: {
            source: true
        },
        child2: {
            source: true
        }
    },
    parent2: {
        child3: {
            source: true
        },
        child4: {
            source: false
        }
    },
    parent3: {
        child5: {
                source: false
        }
    }
}
```

I want the outcome to be:

```
var afterFilter = {
    parent1: {
        child1: {
            source: true
        },
        child2: {
            source: true
        }
    },
    parent2: {
        child3: {
            source: true
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: your input object and output object are same. am i correct ?

Comment: Why are they the same? the output excludes children whose source is false and also exclude parents who dont have any qualifying children. so they are different. But structure wise, yes they are the same, I want to keep the structure.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a solution with a reuseable function, I suggest looking at this implementation.

```js
const data = {parent1:{child1:{source:true},child2:{source:true}},parent2:{child3:{source:true},child4:{source:false}},parent3:{child5:{source:false}}}

function objectMapReduce (object, map, filter) {
  // iterate key-value pairs of object
  return Object.entries(object).reduce(
    (accumulator, [key, value]) => {
      // map each value in object
      const result = map(value, key, object)
      // filter each mapped value
      return filter(result, key, object)
        ? Object.assign(accumulator, { [key]: result })
        : accumulator
    },
    // initial value of accumulator
    {}
  )
}

const afterFilter = objectMapReduce(
  data, // map-reduce each parent in data
  parent => objectMapReduce(
    parent, // map-reduce each child in parent
    ({ source}) => ({ source }), // copy each child
    ({ source }) => source // keep child if source is true
  ),
  parent => Object.keys(parent).length > 0 // keep non-empty parent
)

console.log(afterFilter)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this using ***[`Array.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)*** and ***[`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries)*** , for each parent *entry* iterate through the children of the parent object filter it based on the `source`.

If the current child of the parent has the source as `true` then add it to the accumulator `acc` of the reduce else ignore it:

```js
const data = {parent1:{child1:{source:true},child2:{source:true}},parent2:{child3:{source:true},child4:{source:false}},parent3:{child5:{source:false}}};

const res = Object.entries(data).reduce((acc, [key, value]) =>{
  for(child in value){ //value is the child-object of the parent, iterating throgh all the key of the child and checking if the source is true for this key of the child
    if(value[child].source){
      acc[key] = {...acc[key], [child] : value[child]}; //using spread operator to preserve previous values
    }
  }
  return acc;
}, {});
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using Array methods, you can also try a simple `for...of` loop:

```js
var data = {
  parent1: {
    child1: {
      source: true
    },
    child2: {
      source: true
    }
  },
  parent2: {
    child3: {
      source: true
    },
    child4: {
      source: false
    }
  },
  parent3: {
    child5: {
      source: false
    }
  }
}

var afterFilter = {};

for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(data)){

  for (const [k, v] of Object.entries(value)){

    const { source } = v;

    if (source !== true)
      continue;

    // If `afterFilter[key]` does not exist, init with {}
    afterFilter[key] = afterFilter[key] || {};
    afterFilter[key][k] = { source };

  }

}

console.log(afterFilter)
```

Answer (score -1):

If you find to find whose children is true and return that parent, maybe this is correct answer for you

```
const data = [
{ name: 'parent1', parent : { child: { source : true } } },
{ name: 'parent2', parent : { child: { source : true } } },
{ name: 'parent3', parent : { child: { source : false } } }
```

];

```
const newData = data.filter((e)=> e.parent.child.source === true);
console.log(newData);
```

Comment: This isn't applicable in OP's case since they do not have an array of objects.

Answer (score -1):

This is my solution. Try this

```js
var data = {
    parent1: {
        child1: {
            source: true
        },
        child2: {
            source: true
        }
    },
    parent2: {
        child3: {
            source: true
        },
        child4: {
            source: false
        }
    },
    parent3: {
        child5: {
                source: false
        }
    }
}

var afterFilter = {}


for(var key in data){

    for(var childkey in data[key]){

        if(data[key][childkey].source){

            if(afterFilter[key])
                afterFilter[key][childkey] = data[key][childkey]
            else
                afterFilter[key] = {[childkey]: data[key][childkey]}

        }
            
    }

}

console.log(afterFilter);
```